# AWS SES does not send emails using SendRawEmail operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ses

I have troubles sending emails with AWS golang sdk using [`SendRawEmail`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/ses/#SES.SendRawEmail) operation. Even though I get no errors and receive MessageId back from AWS, I do not receive the email.

Sending emails using [`SendEmail`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/ses/#SES.SendEmail) works fine and I receive the email.

My code:

```
  session, err := session.NewSession()
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  svc := ses.New(session, &aws.Config{Region: aws.String("eu-west-1")})

  messageContent := `From: "Alice" <xxx@xxx>
To: "Bob" <xxx@xxx>
Return-Path: <xxx@xxx>
Subject: Hello
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0

This is a test email`

  base64messageContent := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(messageContent))

  source := aws.String("xxx@xxx")
  destinations := []*string{aws.String("xxx@xxx")}
  message := ses.RawMessage{Data: []byte(base64messageContent)}

  input := ses.SendRawEmailInput{Source: source, Destinations: destinations, RawMessage: &message}

  output, err := svc.SendRawEmail(&input)

  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  log.Println("Response from SES", output)

  return nil
}
```

I am using my Gmail as the destination email, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Receiving a MessageId from the response means the call to `SendRawEmail` was successful. However, it does not necessarily indicate a successful delivery. In order to troubleshoot the issue further, I suggest you inspect the delivery (or bounce) status by [configuring an Amazon SNS notification for SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-sns-notifications.html#configure-feedback-notifications-console) and subscribe your email to the SNS topic to see the delivery status or any reason for failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Data` in `RawData` should not be base64 encoded. As [documentation states](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/ses/#RawMessage):

> // Data is automatically base64 encoded/decoded by the SDK.